# Can I intercept control-A keypresses on IE?

Tags: jquery, events, internet-explorer, keypress

I'm trying to use jQuery to intercept control-A keypresses on my web page, like so:

```
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && (event.which == 65 || event.which == 97)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // ...
    }
});
```

This works on Firefox, but on IE7, my event handler doesn't get called, and all of the text on the page gets selected instead (as happens on Firefox without the event handler).

Is there any way I can intercept control-A's on IE?

Comment: I think the problem is your parameter name.  Just call it `e` instead of the pre-defined `event`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works under FF 3.5 and IE7 for me:

```
    $(function() {
        var isCtrl = false; 

        $(document).keyup(function (e) { 
            if(e.keyCode == 17)
                isCtrl = false;
        }).keydown(function (e) { 
            if(e.keyCode == 17)
                isCtrl = true;

            if(e.keyCode == 65 && isCtrl == true) {
                alert('Intercepted CTRL+A');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Stumbled upon this trying to do the same w/ Ctrl+A.  This cool trick no longer seems to work in Edge or IE11 on Windows 10.  Makes me sad that the only sucky part about developing on Linux is that when you get to testing in M$ you find 8 things that work on EVERY browser and platform except IE/Edge.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a return false in the event handler then it will cancel the browsers behavior.  Depending on the browser it can behave differently (for instance keypress will still fire on firefox after a keydown has canceled it, while IE will stop it).