# Allow number and paste in input text box

Tags: jquery, keydown

I am trying to restrict my input box to have number only. For that I am using following code:

```
$('.onlyNumType').keydown(function(event) {
    var num = event.keyCode;
    if ((num >= 48 && num <= 57) || 
        (num >= 96 && num <= 105) || 
         num == 8 || num == 9 || num == 37 || num == 39 || num == 46) {
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

But I am not able to paste into these text box too. Is there a condition to allow paste operation? I tried to allow Ctrl and V key but it accept V character too.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173460/bind-multiple-keys-to-keypress-event) post

Comment: Yes this post helped but now text box have anything it was pasted even characters.

Comment: Can you then attach the event to the onchange event (there also seems to be a paste event that you can tap into) and cancel the event if there are non-number characters?

Comment: Nevermind .. I called the validation on form submission. So it is getting caught when form submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try HTML5 `input` event:

```
$('.onlyNumType').on('input', function(e) {
    // Beware, this will get called even if user hits `CTRL+V`!
    // In a nutshell, this will be triggered every time input changes.
});
```

However, note that setting value programmatically like

```
$('.onlyNumType').val('Hiya!')
```

will NOT trigger this event.